# How to erase cv::circle from display window

Tags: c++, opencv, drawimage

I use OpenCV library for drawing circles on image.
I need to erase last circle which was drawn on window by clicking on right button click.
Currently, I wrote workaround, I replace red circle by white.
but seems there is another solution such as erase it.
How I can update my UI?

```
std::vector<Point2f> right_image;    // stores 4 points that the user clicks(mouse left click) in the main image.


if (e == EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN && right_image.size() > 0) {
            float x0 = right_image[right_image.size()-1].x;
            float y0 = right_image[right_image.size()-1].y;
            cv::circle(dispImg, cv::Point(x0, y0), 10, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 3);
            cv::imshow(cv::String(fullWindowName), dispImg);
            right_image.pop_back();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be faster to store image without any overlays, and redraw circles each frame. If you want to append, move or delete circle just remove it from the list of objects to plot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing a raster drawing program you could implement a simple undo. You would have to use an off-screen image (`dispImg`) and a smaller 'undo' image. Before drawing the circle on the off-screen image, save the part of the image that will be occupied by the new circle into a new, smaller image. You must also save the position of the image. Then when you want to erase the circle, copy the saved image back to the off-screen image to the position that was saved along with the undo image. Finally, draw the off-screen image to the window (`imshow`).

You could extend this to multiple levels of undo, assuming you have enough memory.

If your program is a vector drawing program, a display list like the one suggested by Andrey is a better option.